# Dynamic html partials - Access Entity Framework property when I only have a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

So I'm not even certain that I'm approaching this the correct way, so if not, please, by all means suggest another approach.
The situation is that I would like to have a main View, with 1 of multiple child views that will change dynamically. For simplification, let's say my main object/entity is "person", which has typical person fields like first name, last name, etc. it also has optional relationships to other tables which contain profession specific information. So on my pages to create, edit, etc. I'd like to offer a  element with the list of professions, that will dynamically replace some `<div id="professionData">` with a strongly typed partial that I've created. This create form would have a single submit which submits the parent and child models.
I've actually got a semi-working solution in place, which on the MVC controller creates a new object based on the type of profession passed in, and hands that off to the partial view as the model.

The problem that I'm having currently is that I'm not sure how to link that child model back to the model used for the main page.

My thought was to just link it on the MVC controller, something like

```
person.doctorData = emptyDoctorData;
```

Where person is an instance of the person object(reloaded from EF, from passed in ID)
I've learned how to create my child object dynamically with a passed in string that identifies the type, ie "doctorData"
But I'm not sure how to access the navigation property on person when I only have the string. it'd be nice to be able to do something like.

```
public PartialView LoadPartial(int personId,string extraDataType){    
PersonType person = repository.FirstOrDefault(x.Id == personId);
var extraData = Activator.CreateInstance(extraDataType);
person.Property(extraDataType)=extraData;
string partialURL="Views/Partials/"+extraDataType;
return PartialView(partialURL,person);
}
```

The CreatInstance is a very sortened version,and won't work in this scenario as is. This is not my actual code, but overly simplified.
**The person.Property line is the one hanging me up**. Not sure how to set the navigation property only having the string that identifies it.  Plus I'm not even sure this is the "correct" way to go about it.  Once I get back to the view, will MVC properly link, this new person model in the partial, with the one that is in the parent view? will they be properly linked on the submit/post?
Also right now, the partial contains it's own form, but I think I need to take that sub-form out and just include it in the parent view (ie. "Person") form.

The person class, which is generated. We're using the EF DB modeler. would look something like.

```
public class Person{
public Person();

public int Id {get;set;}
public string LastName {get;set;}
public string FirstName {get;set;}
public string Profession {get;set;}

public virtual DoctorData  DoctorData {get;set;}
public virtual TeacherData TeacherData {get;set;}
public virtual LawyerData  LawyerData {get;set;}
public virtual ClerkData  ClerkData {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a navigation property set up on your models? Can you share the source for your models?

Comment: Oh yea, I can't use the razor helpers, I don't think, because I don't know which profession will be selected. I really think I need to somehow do an async call to the server to populate the fields depending on which type is selected.
so the @Html.RenderPartial, I don't think would work for me.
Also we're using AngularJS and JQuery, so those are available.

Comment: I do have optional navigation properties on the "Person" Object for each of the child objects.
I'm just using the standard EF model for my view. I've not created a separate veiw model.
Apologize if I'm using any terminology incorrectly, I'm fairly new at this.

Comment: Have gotten over the one minor hurdle with
    var property = typeof(Person).GetProperty(extraDataType);    
    property.SetValue(person, extraData);

This will set the navigation property which is named by the string in "extraDataType" and set it with extraData, ie attach the object extraData to person.

Comment: I think this will still cause me some issues. I'm working on a solution that involves something similar, however rather than trying to load it when I load the partial, I just take the type as a parameter to my Create action, and then add the extra child object there. Then when the user changes the select (dropdownlist) it reloads the page with the new type.